# Request to merge tags fedora13 and fedora-13

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please merge tags fedora13 and fedora-13.

Only a small number of questions are tagged with either of these and they clearly point to the same release of fedora.

Answer (score 4):

The [fedora-13](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora-13) tag has been *synonymed* to [fedora13](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora13) and is just a faint memory now.